# Exception thrown when adding an element into a SetHash declared as "state %set is SetHash[Str]" inside a loop

Tags: raku, sethash

Adding a Str element into a SetHash declared as `state %set is SetHash[Str]` inside a loop throws an exception:

> Cannot resolve caller STORE(SetHash[Str]:U: SetHash[Str]:D); none of these signatures match:
>
> (SetHash:D: *@pairs, *%_ --> SetHash:D)
>
> (SetHash:D: \objects, \bools, *%_ --> SetHash:D)
>
> (QuantHash:D: |)

When declared before the loop as `my %set is SetHash[Str]` the same code works just fine.

According to https://docs.raku.org/type/SetHash#Creating_SetHash_objects :

> ...
>
> Since 6.d (2019.03 and later) it is also possible to specify the type of values you would like to allow in a SetHash.
>
> #### This can either be done when calling .new:
>
> `#only allow Pairs`
>
> `my $n = SetHash[Pair].new: "zero" => 0, "one" => 1, "two" => 2;`
>
> #### or using the masquerading syntax:
>
> `#only allow strings`
>
> `my %sh is SetHash[Str] = <a b c>;`
>
> `say %sh<a>;  # True`
>
> `say %sh<d>;  # False`
>
> ...

When the HashSet is declared the former way (`%set = SetHash[Str].new`) it works as expected (before or inside the loop).
The problem emerges just with the latter.

What works:

```
use v6.d;

my @list = 'aaa' .. 'ddd';

my %set is SetHash[Str];

for @list {
    %set{$_}++ if m/a.*a/;

    LAST {
        put %set.elems;
    }
}
#outputs 10
```

What doesn't:

```
use v6.d;

my @list = 'aaa' .. 'ddd';

for @list {
    state %set is SetHash[Str];

    %set{$_}++ if m/a.*a/;

    LAST {
        put %set.elems;
    }
}
#outputs the exception
```

Why is that? Is this a bug?

(tested with the same results on Rakudo 2019.07.1 and 2019.03)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's something up with `is Foo` on a `state` declaration.

See, for example [[BUG] `state` with `% is SetHash` ends up with a type object on second entry to block](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131508).

I recall also having to write:

```
my @array is BigArray;
proto A(Int \, Int \) { @array[][] //= {*} }
```

instead of

```
proto A(Int \, Int \) { (state @array is BigArray)[][] //= {*} }
```

a while back, so I think there's something more general than just `SetHash`s.